# Displaying frequently changing data in a data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables, electron

I am using data tables to display dynamic data which keeps changing, the data is stored in an array and the array length keeps changing(might increase or decrease). I have set an interval of 1000 milliseconds to keep the data table updated. But since I am using paging, whenever I go to a different page rather from page 1, I am redirected back to page 1 automatically when the data table gets refreshed every 1000 milliseconds (one second). Is there any way which can help me to prevent this? I don't think we can stop the reloading of data table when data gets updated, but I am looking for ideas/hacks one can do to prevent this issue. One simple alternative is to use a button which when clicked refreshes the table rather than auto-refreshing with some interval.

```
fun1 = setInterval(() => {
    if (names.length >= 0 ) {
        var namesArray = names.map((device) => {
            return Object.keys(device).map((key) => {
                return device[key]
            });
        });


        if (Table != undefined) {
            Table.destroy();
        }

        Table = $('#ID1').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            data: namesArray,
            paging: true,
            searching: false,
            oLanguage: {
                "sEmptyTable": " "
            },
            ordering: false,
            info: false,
            columns: [
                { title: "Name" },
                { title: "Age" },
            ],
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```

}

Comment: Keep the page # in a cookie or in the route. When refreshing, provide the page number and auto-refresh to that page number.

Comment: I am using this for a desktop app using electron. So I don't think this works at least for a desktop app.

Comment: Probably want to change one of your tags to Electron. I'm sorry I'm not familiar enough with that to help you.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate that. Thank You.